# Assuming that it was enciphered with a generalized Caesar cipher with multiplier...

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Assuming that it was enciphered with a generalized Caesar cipher with multiplier $r$ and shift constant $s$, find $r$ and $s$ and decipher the message:

ZWSTO BPJOG BYQIP JOUWO OZGVS MPJOS MPQAI

- So this section we're covering is on the Caesar Ciphers which I understand the process of and have completed several problems that had to do with basic given shift constant decryption and encryption. Although I don't really understand how I am to go about finding the values for $r$ and $s$. Any hints/help are really appreciated.

Comment: I would start by looking at the letters that appear most often in the message, and compare them to numbers that are used most frequently in English.

Comment: Is there some kind of formula applicable to this, or a bit of brute force to get the ball rolling?

Comment: Yes brute force could help. Especially if you have a digital word-book so you could automatically check.

Comment: Suppose, for example, that you suspect that code $A$ is deciphered to $E$, and $C$ to $S$. Then, since $A,C,E,S$ are at places $1,3,5,19$ in the alphabet, you would have the equations $1r + s \equiv 5 \pmod {26}$ and $3r + s \equiv 19 \pmod {26}$. Do you see how you would proceed from there?

Comment: Note that since $26 = 2\cdot 13$, if two code letters are a multiple of $2$ (respectively $13$) apart, then the corresponding deciphered letters will also be a multiple of $2$ (or $13$) apart. The most common letter in the coded message is $O$, and the letter $13$ away from that is $B$. You could look for two common letters in English that are $13$ away from each other.

Comment: In the coded message, the letters with odd parity are AGIMOQSUWY, and there are almost twice as many of these as the letters with even parity. Out of the commonest letters in English (ETAOINSHR), most have odd parity. So we can guess that the letters of odd parity correspond to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Make a table showing the frequency of each letter. You’ll find that one is much more common than the others, so it’s worth taking the time to investigate the possibility that it represents E, which is by far the most common letter in ordinary English prose. The second most common letter in English is T, again by a noticeable margin, and there is one letter in the message that stands out as being second most common in the message; we might as well see whether we can make any progress guessing that it represents T. Then you’ll find that every time the resulting plaintext would have the sequence T.E, with one letter between the T and the E, **it’s the same letter in the middle**; what’s the obvious guess for that letter?

That gives you three congruences of the form $rx+s\equiv y\pmod{26}$ with known values of $x$ and $y$. If you subtract one of them from another, you eliminate $s$ and get a congruence involving only $r$, something of the form $ru\equiv v\pmod{26}$. Of the three congruences that you can in this way, one can be solved very easily for $r$, and you can check that the same value of $r$ satisfies each of the others as well. You can then go back to the original congruences of the form $rx+s\equiv y\pmod{26}$ and solve for $s$. Make sure that they all yield the same value of $s$: this tells you that your guesses at the letters representing T, E, and the third one are at least consistent.

If you’ve done everything right so far, you’ll find that they *are* consistent. You can then test your values of $r$ and $s$ by trying to complete the decipherment; if you get meaningful text (and you will, if you’ve done everything right so far), you have the right $r$ and $s$.

Cryptanalysis, even of such a simple cipher as this, usually involves a lot more trial and error, but this time we’re lucky: the first reasonable hypothesis turns out to work.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to justify downvoting a correct answer?